# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. ParseExact - Just Date

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-format

I've tried with several different format strings but I can't get it to parse a date like:

```
date = "10/16/13";
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: Why do you use dashes? You have to use `@"M\/dd\/yy"`.

Comment: replace / by - or vice-versa

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at what exactly ParseExact does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to parse the date your format needs to be the same.  Change "M-dd-yy" to "M/dd/yy"  Assuming that the month is a single digit and the day is always 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this should work just fine. You just need to be aware that it will set a default time of 12:00 am because you are not specifying the time in your string.

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string date = "10/16/13";

        //This is usually the safer way to go
        DateTime result;
        if(DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        //I think this is what you were trying to accomplish
        DateTime result2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```